# I thought that pointers store the address of another variable so I am confused

Tags: c++, pointers

> Which statement is/are NOT true about the following code (More than one answer may be selected)?
>
> ```
> int x = 1;
> int* p1 = &x;
> int** p2 = &p1;
> ```
>
> A. p1 is a pointer to the memory address of x.
> B. *p1 holds the address of x.
> C. p2 is a pointer to the memory address of *p1.
> D. p2 holds the address of p1.

The answer to this question is B and C. I am confused, as I thought a pointer held the address of a variable. Once you dereference a pointer, it uses that address to return the value at that address.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [What does *p = &x actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72327708/what-does-p-x-actually-mean)

Comment: Not your fault, but this is the most confusing possible way to phrase this question. I've been writing C++ for nearly a decade, and I had to read it three or four times to figure out what on earth it was asking.

Comment: Also, @AnoopRana, that question is deleted, so OP can't see it. Only 10k+ users can see deleted questions.

Comment: *A. p1 is a pointer to the memory address of x* I'd word it differently. A. p1 is a pointer to x. Its *value* is the address of x.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, i agree. I said the same in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72327871/12002570) and also in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72327708/what-does-p-x-actually-mean#comment127778382_72327871).

Comment: As worded, A is also incorrect.  There is no such thing as "a pointer to a memory address" -- a pointer is a memory address and "points at" memory.

Comment: @ChrisDodd, In all sane interpretations of English and C/C++, "a pointer to `x`" is the same as "a pointer to the memory locations of `x`". After all, we're trying to teach the basics of programming here, not splitting linguistic hairs.

Comment: My point is that the question is badly worded an ambiguous.  Depending on how much you contort the ambiguities of english, most of the answers could be considered either true or false.

Answer (score 0):

> A. `p1` is a pointer to the memory address of `x`.

This is true. The `&` takes the address of an object.

> B. `*p1` holds the address of `x`.

This is false. `p1` holds the address of `x`. The `*` in `*p1` follows the pointer, so `*p1` is the value of `x`.

> C. `p2` is a pointer to the memory address of `*p1`

False, `p2` is a pointer to the memory address of `p1`. Technically, `*p1` doesn't have a memory address since it's not an object by itself.

> D. `p2` holds the address of `p1`.

True.

A note about the language, in this context, "holds the address of *var*" is the same thing as "is a pointer to *var*" and "is a pointer to the memory address of *var*".

Comment: A is false.  p1 is a pointer to x, and is the memory address of x.  It is not "a pointer to a memory address", which makes no sense.

Comment: My lecturer said A is correct as p1 contains / points to the memory address/location of x, so *p1 contains the value of x.  Therefore A is true and B is false.

Comment: @ChrisDodd, you should read "pointer to `x`" as equivalent of "pointer to the memory address of `x`". Hence,A is true.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I also think the same(that A is incorrect). I even mentioned this in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72327871/12002570) and also argued exactly this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72327708/what-does-p-x-actually-mean#comment127777731_72327708) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72327708/what-does-p-x-actually-mean#comment127778382_72327871).

Comment: "a pointer to the memory address of x" would be interpreted by most English speakers as the same as "a pointer to storage containing the memory address of x" (which describes p2, but not p1).